# Deconvolution (conv2d_transpose) in tensor flow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a trained network ([AlexNet](https://www.nvidia.cn/content/tesla/pdf/machine-learning/imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-nn.pdf)) for image classification; currently, I am trying to visualize the feature activation of different convolutional layers using deconvolution technique proposed by [Zeiler](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf). I am getting the following in results:

`Input shape: (1,227,227,3)`
`Filter shape: (11,11,3,96)`
`stride = (4,4)`

For getting the convolution output I used the following code:

```
wts = model.layers[1].get_weights()
inp = tf.constant(x_test)
ftr = tf.constant(wts[0])
b = tf.constant(wts[1])
c = tf.nn.conv2d(inp, ftr, strides = [1,4,4,1], padding='VALID')
c = c + b

sess = tf.Session()
res = sess.run(c)
print(res.shape)
sess.close()

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
for i in range(96):
    plt.subplot(10, 10, i+1)
    img = res[0,:,:,i]
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.xticks(np.array([]))
    plt.yticks(np.array([]))
    plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Following is the result which appears to be correct
[image]
But when I am trying the inverse operation I was expecting to get the original image but I am getting something else. Please help me understand why I didn't get anything close to the original image.

```
inp = tf.constant(res)
ftr = tf.constant(wts[0])
b   = tf.constant(wts[1])
c = inp - b
c = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(c, ftr, output_shape = [1,227,227,3], strides = [1,4,4,1], padding='VALID')

sess = tf.Session()
res = sess.run(c)
print(res.shape)
sess.close()

plt.imshow(res[0,:,:,:])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you fixed the issue. Try using:

```
c = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(c, filters = 3, kernel_size = (11,11))
```

And see where it gets you instead of initial *tf.nn.conv2d_transpose*. 
I would love your feedback even if you already solved the issue.